# SQL Server: How to replace words in one column if/when the same word is found in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, find, lookup-tables

I'm trying to analyze some data. I'm new to SQL. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! I've spent hours searching for a solution, but as far as I can tell most searches of this nature require a common key, which there isn't in this case.

I have a column within a table that lists the favorite foods of respondents.

```
Column 1
------------------------
Banana, Tomato, Carrot 
Orange, Apple, Chicken
Peas, Potatoes, Spinach
```

In separate tables, I have created a list of the various foods by category (fruit, meat, vegetable, etc) including possible misspellings. For example:

```
Fruit
---------
Banana
Bannana
Pear
Oear
```

If an item from the Fruit column is found within Column 1, I need to replace it with the term "fruit". I need to repeat this for all of the categories, until it looks something like this:

```
Column 1
------------------
[Fruit][Fruit][Vegetable]
[Fruit][Fruit][Meat]
[Vegetable][Vegetable][Vegetable]
```

I have massive amounts of data and will need to repeat this process on other data in the future. Any thoughts on how this might be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: . . Such is the pain you cause yourself when you don't store values in form more suitable for relational databases.  I would suggest that you take CraftyDBAs advice.

Answer (score 1):

I guess my question is "why keep the data in a list format after processing?".  This format is not in [normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

I would create the following tables.

```
raw_data 
(
user_id,
food_list
)

categories
(
  food_name,
  food_category
)

processed_data
(
  user_id,
  food_category,
  food_cnt
)

hospital_data
(
  user_id,
  unknown_name
)
```

The raw_data table is the unprocessed data.  I would use a string split function to parse the data into rows.  Convert the data to same case and compare against food category.

Any matches should be counted and saved in the processed_data().  Any left over names w/o match should be put in the hospital_data() table.  These are miss spelled entries that need to be added to the category table.

This solution would be a two pass run.

1 - Loads most of the data.

2 - Manually add misspelled name to category table, reprocess hospital_data() table.
    Remove data from hospital table and [UPSERT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29) (MERGE) data counts in processed_data() table.

Sample data using tuple notation.

```
raw_data 
(1, Banana, Tomato, Carrot)
(2, Orange, Apple, Chicken)
(3, Peas, Potatoes, pinach)

processed_data 
(1, Fruit, 2)
(1, Vegetable, 1)
(2, Fruit, 2)
(2, Meat, 1)
(3, Vegetable, 2)

hospital_data
(3, pinach)
```

Answer (score 0):

I base on your 'first' question to come out this. Not sure good enough to answer you 'second' question :)

1. create split function

   ```
   create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnString_DelimeterIndex]
   (
       @Text NVARCHAR(4000),
       @Delimiter CHAR,
       @Section SMALLINT
   )
   RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
   AS

   BEGIN
       DECLARE @NextPos SMALLINT,
           @LastPos SMALLINT,
           @Found SMALLINT,
           @REVERSE BIT

       IF @Section < 0
           SELECT  @Text = REVERSE(@Text)--, @Section=1,@REVERSE=1

       SELECT  @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, 1),
           @LastPos = 0,
           @Found = 1

       WHILE @NextPos > 0 AND ABS(@Section) <> @Found
           SELECT  @LastPos = @NextPos,
               @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, @NextPos + 1),
               @Found = @Found + 1


       RETURN  CASE
               WHEN @Found <> ABS(@Section) OR @Section = 0 THEN NULL
               --WHEN @REVERSE =1 THEN 
               WHEN @Section > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END)
               ELSE REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END))
           END
   END
   ```
2. Select result, and assume you will have 3 fix data in column1 ( means will sure each row have this format of data -->'data1,data2,data3')

   create table #Tbl (column1 varchar(50))
   create table #Tbl2 (category varchar(50),column1 varchar(50))

   ```
   insert into #Tbl values('Banana, Tomato, Carrot'),('Orange, Apple, Chicken'),('Peas, Potatoes, Spinach')

   insert into #Tbl2 values('Fruit','Banana'),('Fruit','Bananana'),('Vege','Tomato'),('Vege','Carrot')



   select '[' + isnull(tbl2.category,'NA') + ']' +
   '[' + isnull(tbl2_1.category,'NA') + ']' +
   '[' + isnull(tbl2_2.category ,'NA')+ ']' 
   from #Tbl tbl1
   left join #Tbl2 tbl2 ON rtrim(ltrim(dbo.fnString_DelimeterIndex(tbl1.column1,',',1))) = tbl2.column1
   left join #Tbl2 tbl2_1 ON rtrim(ltrim(dbo.fnString_DelimeterIndex(tbl1.column1,',',2))) = tbl2_1.column1
   left join #Tbl2 tbl2_2 ON rtrim(ltrim(dbo.fnString_DelimeterIndex(tbl1.column1,',',3))) = tbl2_2.column1
   ```